# Loops & Control Flow

Tags: javascript

When I run this I can't seem to get the rest of the values.
Write a function `mergingTripletsAndQuints` which takes in two arrays as arguments. This function will return a new array replacing the elements in `array1` if they are divisible by 3 or 5. The number should be replaced with the sum of itself added to the element at the corresponding index in `array2`.

```js
function mergingTripletsAndQuints(array1, array2) {
  let result = [];
  let ctr = 0;
  let x = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
      ctr = array1[i] + array2[j];
      if (ctr % 3 === 0 || ctr % 5 === 0) {
        result.push(ctr);
      } else {
        return array1[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(mergingTripletsAndQuints([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15], [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])); // expected log [1, 2, 9, 4, 13, 24]
console.log(mergingTripletsAndQuints([1, 1, 3, 9, 5, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // expected log [1, 1, 6, 13, 10, 21]
```

It is only logging `[1], [1]`

Comment: I don't think your code does what you describe above. I'd write `const result = array1.map((v,i) => v%3 && v%5 ? v : v + array2[i])`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I suppose there is a typo returning `array1[i]` in nested loop. I suppose you mean `result.push(array1[i])` instead.

I think it should be something like this:

```js
function mergingTripletsAndQuints(array1, array2) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i]% 3 === 0 || array1[i]% 5 === 0) {
      result.push(array1[i] + array2[i]);
    } else {
      result.push(array1[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(mergingTripletsAndQuints([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15], [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])); // expected log [1, 2, 9, 4, 13, 24]
console.log(mergingTripletsAndQuints([1, 1, 3, 9, 5, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // expected log [1, 1, 6, 13, 10, 21]
```

Comment: Please add explanation of what's changed and why.

Comment: Got it. Added some exploration.

Comment: The problem seems to ask to replace if **the elements in array1 are divisible by 3 or 5**, not the sum

Comment: I edited your answer to add a Stack Snippet, and the logs of the outputs of the edited function. As you can see, it logs `undefined` instead of `1` for each call. Not sure that's better :). I think you want to `return result;` after the loops. Also, what @kikon said :)

Answer (score 0):

A nested for loop is not necessary, look at this code:

```
function mergingTripletsAndQuints(array1, array2) {
let sum = [];
for (let i = 0; Math.max(i < array1.length, i < array2.length); i++) {
    if (array1[i] % 3 == 0 || array1[i] % 5 == 0) {
        sum.push(array1[i] + array2[i])
    } else {
        sum.push(array1[i])
    }
}
return sum;
```

}